# Trying to analyze two time intervals - my WHERE subquery returns too many rows

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime

I want to extract all cases of *id_hand* from table *public.statistics* that fall into certain time intervals. *date_played* is a variable of type timestamp. In *schema_b.table_80perc* there are two datapoints *date_played* for *id_player* 789 (these are the datapoints that indicate the “start time” for the two time intervals in *public.statistics* that interest me).

I think therefore  I get the following error:

*more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression*

How could I possibly solve this problem?

```
SELECT id_hand
FROM public.statistics
  WHERE id_player = 789 
  AND date_played between (SELECT date_played 
                           FROM schema_b.table_80perc) 
                  and (SELECT date_played 
                       FROM schema_b.table_80perc) + interval '5 minutes'
```

edit: sample data

*public.statistics*

[image]

*schema_b.table_80perc*

[image]

*schema_b.table_80perc* is a subset from *public.statistics*

In this case here, I ultimately need all *id.hand* from *public.statistics* that are in the time intervals
05:34:12 + 5 minutes
05:47:10 + 5 minutes

I need to automate this for other player id´s later so I need it automated using these two tables.

Comment: Please show us sample data of the tables. First thing I would say: Your selects in the WHERE clause should only deliver one value not a whole dataset. Helping you to get the expected result you should add sample data and expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `EXISTS` subquery:

```
SELECT id_hand
FROM   public.statistics AS ps
WHERE  id_player = 789 
AND EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM   schema_b.table_80perc AS ss
    WHERE  ss.id_player = ps.id_player
    AND    ps.date_played >= ss.date_played 
    AND    ps.date_played <  ss.date_played + INTERVAL '5 minutes'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a bit shady, but with the data you've given us, this should do:

```
SELECT id_hand
FROM public.statistics s
  WHERE id_player = 789 
  AND date_played between (SELECT min(date_played) + interval '5 minutes'
                           FROM schema_b.table_80perc t
                           where t.id_player = s.id_player) 
                  and (SELECT max(date_played) + interval '5 minutes'
                       FROM schema_b.table_80perc
                       where t.id_player = s.id_player)
```